# Absolute positioning within relative positioning issue

Tags: html, css, css-position, vertical-alignment

I'm a complete novice at absolute positioning, and i can't work out why the H2 text in the div is being horizontally centered... I'm only trying to center it vertically.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="column1"> 
        <div class="alignCenter">
            <img  style="float:left;width:40%;min-width:300px;max-width:400px;" src="http://dummyimage.com/500x500/000/fff.png&text=SampleImage" alt="">
            <h2 style="float:left;width:60%;max-width:850px";>Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla!Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! Bla! </h2><br style="clear:both">       
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.alignCenter{
    position:relative;
    width:70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.alignCenter h2{
    position:absolute;
    top:30%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gpRDc/

Comment: Because it's inside a horizontally centered `<div>`?

Comment: That's not what i mean. Just look at the jsFiddle

Comment: I have done, what's your problem? What is your expected result?

Comment: It should be centered vertically, such as the second div. Different JSFIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/kX4bh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your `div` is constraining the `h2`--that is, because you have the `width: 70%;`, your `div` is only taking up 70% of the screen.  Yet the entire `div` itself is centered, due to the `margin: 0 auto;` property you have applied.  Therefore, both the image and the text are appearing at the left-most boundary of the `div`.

The reason the first image isn't at the right like the second one is because you haven't applied the `float: right;` property to it, instead you have it at `float: left;`.

If you want the image to be offset from the text, you will have to give it its own position within the `div`.  Otherwise, make the `div` width wider, then apply the position properties to the image and the `h2` respectively.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kX4bh/2/.  Notice how I made the width of the `div` to be the full screen, and offset the image by using the `left: 20px;` style.

I'm not sure what specifically you are trying to accomplish so I can't be any more specific in my answer then this.  If you clarify what you need then I can help you more.

Comment: What i didn't know about relatively/absolutely positioned elements is that they're removed from their inherented state and this needed either the correct floats, or left/right absolute values. Thanks for the answer though, very detailed.